# How does spring integration error message routing work?

Tags: java, error-handling, spring-integration

I have configured my spring integration app to manage errors like this :

```
<exception-type-router resolution-required="true" default-output-channel="errorChannelStop" input-channel="error-manager">
    <mapping exception-type="org.springframework.xml.validation.XmlValidationException" channel="formatErrorMessageChannel" />
</exception-type-router>
```

However, when I encounter the following exception, it doesn't route the message to the `formatErrorMessageChannel` channel :

```
org.springframework.xml.validation.XmlValidationException: Could not validate source: The element type "messageType" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</messageType>".; 
    nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; line number: 9; columnNumber: 24; The element type "message Type" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</messageType>".
    ...
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The element type "message Type" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</messageType>".
```

Why ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be sure that you send a message into that `error-manager`. Just throwing an exception doesn't make everything working against your error channel.

See docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html/error-handling.html#error-handling